Persistent KieSession in Drools version 9.44.0.Final
Is there a possibility to use Drools Persistent Session in Drools version "9.44.0.Final"?
Drools persistent session in version "7.74.1.Final" uses the "javax" library, but drools version "9.44.0.Final" doesn't contain needed libraries with the "jakarta" library:

org.kie.kie-spring
org.jbpm.jbpm-persistence-api
org.jbpm.jbpm-persistence-jpa

I am using the latest Spring-boot version "3.3.5", and I found incompatibility with older drools version "7.74.1.Final", mainly thanks to the migration of the "javax" library to "jakarta" by the spring-boot upgrade from version 2.x to 3.x.
I need to implement a multi-instance java application operated in the cloud with the drools rule engine, which has shared persistent session affected by Facts. Facts will be inserted from an asynchronous message queue and processed by some of all application instances, and these facts must be shared for all application instances. Is it the correct way to use shared persistent KieSession, or is there in the new version of Drools "9.44.0.Final" better way to achieve the goals described above?
Does anyone know the roadmap of the Drools project if they will include persistent sessions in the new Drools version?
I tried to use the latest Drools with the latest Spring boot and implement the application with the shared persistent session, but it doesn't work because libraries (dependencies) for the persistent session are missing in version "9.44.0.Final" of Drools.
Missing dependencies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
    <version>9.44.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbpm-persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>9.44.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbpm-persistence-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>9.44.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

Latest existing dependencies incompatible with the latest spring-boot 3.x (following dependencies uses "javax" instead of "jakarta"):
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
    <version>7.74.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbpm-persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.74.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbpm-persistence-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>7.74.1.Final</version>
</dependency>


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
